# Check that matrix keys are in running order - python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, iteration

Given a matrix file and the first column is used as the key to a python dictionary (call it docid), how should I read the file such that it stops if the key is not in running order, i.e.

- `if docid-1 > previous_docid` or
- `if docid < previd`

I have been doing it as the code below but it looks a little verbose, is there any other way do producing the same output? (note: solution needs to handle matrix file that can go up to 20 GB. for the sake of a code snippet, i gave a small data set)

```
text = '''0 1 1
0 2 1
1 3 1
1 7 1
2 5 4
2 4 6
2 9 8
3 5 7
3 9 8
3 10 9
9 2 9
9 8 3
3 9 4'''

from collections import defaultdict
docs = defaultdict(list)
previd = -1
for line in text.split('\n'):
    docid, termid, val = map(int,line.split())
    if docid < previd or docid-1 > previd:
        print line
        break
    previd = docid
    docs[docid].append((termid,val))

for i in docs:
    print i, docs[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any simplifications, because the filtering condition depends on the previous element (making potential filtered iteration complex). I don't think your code is complicated but you can define a special traversal:

```
def read_text(text):
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        docid, termid, val = map(int,line.split())
        if docid < previd or docid-1 > previd:
            print line # I guess this is a debug feature
            return # or raise Exception("line not in running order", line)
        yield (docid, termid, val)
```

and in your main code:

```
for docid, termid, val in read_text(text):
    docs[docid].append((termid,val))
```

#### EDIT:

Instead of `text.split('\n')` maybe `open('myfile','r')` is more efficient.

```
for line in open('myfile','r'):
    do_something(line)
```